# Parsing a PKCS #7 using go.mozilla.org/pkcs7 fails with "tags don't match"

Tags: go, pkcs#7

I'm trying to create a PKCS #7 as a test fixture using the following OpenSSL commands (adapted from https://www.ssl.com/guide/pem-der-crt-and-cer-x-509-encodings-and-conversions/):

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes -subj "/C=US/ST=CA/L=San Francisco/O=Acme Corporation/OU=Awesomeness Department/CN=Insanely Great Certificate"
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile cert.pem -out cert.p7b
```

However, if I try parsing it using the [pkcs7](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mozilla.org/pkcs7) package,

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"

    "go.mozilla.org/pkcs7"
)

func main() {
    b, err := os.ReadFile("cert.p7b")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if _, err := pkcs7.Parse(b); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

I get an error that the tags don't match,

```
> go run main.go
panic: asn1: structure error: tags don't match (16 vs {class:0 tag:13 length:77 isCompound:true}) {optional:false explicit:false application:false private:false defaultValue:<nil> tag:<nil> stringType:0 timeType:0 set:false omitEmpty:false} contentInfo @2
```

Should this not be a valid PKCS #7?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `pkcs7.Parse` expects its input to be in DER format whereas the output from OpenSSL is in PEM format by default. So either the program needs to be adapted to

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/pem"
    "os"

    "go.mozilla.org/pkcs7"
)

func main() {
    b, err := os.ReadFile("cert.p7b")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    block, _ := pem.Decode(b)
    if block == nil {
        panic("Input is not in PEM format.")
    }

    if _, err := pkcs7.Parse(block.Bytes); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Or in the `openssl crl2pkcs7` call one needs to specify the `outform` flag as `der`:

```
> openssl crl2pkcs7 --help
unknown option '--help'
usage: crl2p7 [-certfile file] [-in file] [-inform DER | PEM]
    [-nocrl] [-out file] [-outform DER | PEM]

 -certfile file     Chain of PEM certificates to a trusted CA
 -in file           Input file (default stdin)
 -inform format     Input format (DER or PEM (default))
 -nocrl             Do not read CRL from input or include CRL in output
 -out file          Output file (default stdout)
 -outform format    Output format (DER or PEM (default))
```